# Rule-based available values for a property within model

Tags: c#, validation, mvvm, model, viewmodel

I have a question regarding where to put available values of a specific property within a model class. Imagine you have a model class that has two properties Family and Series where the possible values of the Series property depends on the value of the Family property.

The business logic contains a set of rules that defines which Series values are available due to the value specified by the Family property. The model itself should always have a valid state, that means if the value of the Family property changes and the available values of the Series property also change, the value of the Series property itself must be changed to one of the available values to fit the valid state.

My intention is to display the available values within a ComboBox for both the Family property and the Series property. But at the moment I'm not sure whether to put the available values of the Series property

1. into the ViewModel,
2. into the Model,
3. or to introduce a separate layer between ViewModel and Model which covers data validation and the functionality of providing available values for specific properties within the model (that acts as plain data container).

I tend to use the second or third approach (I prefer the third approach) because of the directly dependent values within the model. This example in fact is very simple. The real problem covers about nearly 200 values where the available values of a single property can depend on up to 5 or 10 other properties.

In addition, the dependent values may not be located within a single model class and the concerning model classes do not know each other. So it is possible that the values that are required to get the available values for a property of a model class can be located within two or more other model classes.

What do you think is the best approach? Is there another (better) way to solve this I have not mention above?

Thanks,

Oliver

Comment: Just a comment, not an answer: I think it depends what kind of values you're talking about. In my opinion if they concern to business validation rules they should stay in the Model but if they are "just" text required by a specific UI then they should stay in the ViewModel. I do not agree with the 3rd solution, another layer? Validation or whatever else has to stay in (one) model.

Comment: Thanks. No, these values are not "just" text - they are "real" values :) The approach with the separate layer came from another user here who answered a similar question, but not related to this mass of dependent values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already stated that the Model classes do not know each other, you certainly should not create dependencies just for the purpose of validation/aggregation/filtering (or whatever you might call it) on such a deep layer.

Your requirements generally fit the concerns of a ViewModel which cover value prepation among other things. On the other hand, you don't want to rely on a ViewModel doing that validation given that you model **always** has to be in a valid state. Just imagine you might add another client later that uses your Model data but can't use the ViewModels.

Therefore, an additional "layer" or service might be the best option in my opinion.